# What version of Ubuntu just installed? The "mouse" release?

Tags: gnome, keyboard

I've been running Ubuntu 23.04 Lunar Lobster. The default wallpaper has the lobster as a constellation.

I performed a routine update from the updater.

Now the desktop environment is vastly different. The wallpaper is a colorful maze pattern with a mouse in the center.

`$ lsb_release -a` reports:

`Release: 23.04 Codename: lunar`

`$ echo $XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP` returns

`ubuntu:GNOME`

The keyboard remapping I applied using gnome-tweaks still shows in gnome-tweaks, but has no effect.

How can I return to the standards Gnome Lunar Lobster?

Comment: What do your logs say about the changes?